# How to translate content of the composite element settings?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have created a composite element where I added a custom textarea field in the element settings.

I have added that element in a webform, filled that textarea and saved the webform.

Now I want to translate the webform, But when I go the webform translations, I am unable to translate the value of that text area.

Is there any way to translate the value of that text area?

```
/**
 * Provides a booking element.
 *
 * @WebformElement(
 *   id = "my_element",
 *   label = @Translation("My element"),
 *   category = @Translation("Composite elements"),
 *   multiline = TRUE,
 *   composite = TRUE,
 *   states_wrapper = TRUE,
 * )
 */
class Myelement extends WebformCompositeBase {
  public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state): array {
    $form = parent::form($form, $form_state);

    $form['element']['booking_email'] = [
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => $this->t('some content'),
      '#weight' => '0',
    ];

    return $form;
  }
}
```

Here is the backend of the element settings.
[image]

And here is the webform translation interface. I can't see my textarea field so that I can translate its content. I only see the composite element key and title.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a schema config file to make them translatable.

I have done it like this by creating `my_module.plugin.handler.schema.yml` file in my `my_module/config/schema` directory.

```
webform.handler.my_element:
  type: mapping
  label: Booking email
  mapping:
    booking_email:
      label: 'Something'
      type: text
```